# What is this water explosion under my rocket?

Tags: rocket-explosion, water-powered-flight, waterrocket

I have been experimenting in a team with water rockets. Everything time we film it and play it in slow motion, we always see a “mini explosion” once the bottle runs out of water. What is happening here?

[image: Water rocket launch when out on the field]

[image: Testing the bottle in my back yard at only 2 bars]

Comment: For those wondering why in the second image the bottle is launching right next to a house, the reason is that it was just a launch at only 2 bars. It did not really matter where it landed because it could only fly a few meters. So it was easier to test the launch pad right in my backyard and saved a trip to the launch site.

Comment: Doesn't matter how much pressure it has: it's clearly flying high enough to get stuck on the roof.

Comment: @Mark has happened , but usually it gets stuck in a tree if anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the water is nearly depleted, there is less resistance in the nozzle - the very last bit of water is expelled more rapidly.
Also the layer of water breaks down so it creates a mist together with the also rapidly emerging air - creating a mist.
This is less dense and is thus accellerated more rapidly and also more to the side. And here is the cloud you noticed.

Answer (score 7):

The last little bit of water exits the bottle at higher speed, plus a rush of escaping gas. This impacts the water column and blows it apart.

Answer (score 3):

The gas in the bottle (presumably air) is saturated with water vapor. Assuming the air is still pressurized when the water propellant is exhausted, there is a sudden expansion of the saturated air as it is expelled after the water. This sudden pressure drop causes the condensation.

If I am right, this "explosion" would not be seen if the propellant had a negligible vapor pressure. Try substituting cooking oil. But stand clear !